# Verifying no solution of a system of differential (and algebric) equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, education

How can I verifying in a simple way that the following system of differential (and algebric) equations has not solution? The unknown quantities are $Q_d,C_d,C_a,C_i$ and the boundary conditions are $Q_d(0)=0$ and so on. The quantities $Q_a,k_a,k_d,k_o$ are positive constants.

$$\frac{d\left( Q_d C_d \right) }{dx} = k_d \left( C_i - C_d \right)$$

$$\frac{dQ_d }{dx} = k_o \left( C_d - C_i \right)$$

$$Q_a \frac{dC_a }{dx} = k_a (C_a-C_i)$$

$$k_a (C_a-C_i) = k_d \left( C_i - C_d \right)$$

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: The picture is unreadable. Could you MathJax it instead?

Comment: Seems like $Q_d=C_d=C_a=C_i=0$ is a solution.

Comment: Hello @user254433, sorry I don't specify that unknown quantities are not zero. Thank you.